# Как в C# создать полноэкранное игровое черное окно на Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма. Как ее сделать черной и на весь экран? Как игровое окно, только пустое?
Сделать размеры 1920 на 1080 или как?

Comment: Полноэкранный режим != окно с размером на весь экран

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BackColor = Color.Black; // чёрный цвет фона
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; // отсутствие рамки
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; // полностью распахнутая форма
```